# Google map fragment not fitting in my custom background

Tags: android, google-maps

My requirement is ,[image]

But I am getting as rectangular map only even if the parent layout of map background has corners, my code is ,

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
  >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/white_bg"
            >
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my white_bg code is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Background Color -->
    <solid android:color="@color/white_color" />

    <!-- Border Color -->
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/white_color" />

    <!-- Round Corners -->
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:topRightRadius="@dimen/_12sdp" />


</shape>
```

Please help me to get out of this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved using card view,

this is my solution ,this may help someone

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
  <RelativeLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/white_bg">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
        >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout >
```

Answer (score 0):

Add corners to your Relative layout and use a fragment over it to display the google map. For button over it you can add Frame layout and use it as a button.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/white_bg"
>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

<FrameLayout>

    Button Code Here

</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you can try relative layout and instead of fragment, use frame layout.

Comment: Try FrameLayout for a map fragment and use another frame layout over it.